# Is it possible to use Cacti to monitor MySQL on Amazon's RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cacti

I noticed that the [instructions to setup cacti with mysql](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/wiki/MySQLTemplates) mention granting SUPER priveleges:

> Create a MySQL user with the SUPER and PROCESS privileges on each server you want to monitor

However, it looks like using the Relational Database Service from Amazon (RDS), you cannot grant SUPER privileges.  Does this mean I can't use cacti?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, apparently OP got his answer at AWS forums: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=175788

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is NO.

Since you are aware that cacti needs privileges on MYSQL if you are looking to monitor things like innodb duffer pool, table locks, query cache, checkpoint e.t.c .

I would recommend moving out of RDS if this is possible. If high availability is an issue then you can look into MMM, or galera cache for High availability of you Master server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Here you have the percona documentation.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-plugins/1.1/cacti/rds-templates.html

KR,
Antonio